# onMouseOver with pressed left mouse button (event)

Tags: javascript

In javascript I have events eg.

```
<div id="one" onMouseOver="func()">
```

I want to call a function when somebody hover over on my div but only if left mouse button is pressed and I want to call another function when user release the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, track the mouse down state

```
window.mouseDown = false;
document.onmousedown = function() {
    window.mouseDown = true;
}
document.onmouseup = function() {
    window.mouseDown = false;
}
```

Then in `func()`

```
func = function () {
    if (window.mouseDown) {
        // the mouse is down and hovering div
    }
}
```

Assuming you need an event fired when the user releases mouse while hovering the div :

```
<div id="one" onMouseOver="func();" onMouseOut="func2();">

window.hovering = false;

func = function () {
    window.hovering = true;
    if (window.mouseDown) {
        // the mouse is down and hovering div
    }
}

func2 = function () {
    window.hovering = false;
}

document.onmouseup = function() {
    window.mouseDown = false;
    if (window.hovering) {
        // user released mouse while hovering div
    }
}
```